# Extracting user comments from news website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, screen-scraping

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def wait(dr, x):
  element = WebDriverWait(dr, 50).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, x))
)
return element
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.dinamalar.com/user_comments.asp? uid=14701&name=%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%AE%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%B4%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%9A%E0%AF%86%E0%AE%B2%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%A9%E0%AF%8D")
for elem in wait(browser, '//*[@id="commsec"]/div[2]/div[1]'):
print elem.text
```

This is the link i need to extract all the comments   http://www.dinamalar.com/user_comments.asp?uid=14701&name=%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%AE%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%B4%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%9A%E0%AF%86%E0%AE%B2%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%A9%E0%AF%8D

But my code extracting only the first 10 comments. After clicking the button the other 10 comments are loaded dynamically. How to extract all these comments using python selenium

Answer (score 2):

The idea would be to look for how many "more ideas" elements are present on the page. Every time you click the button and load more comments, one more "more ideas" red button becomes present. Implementation:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
browser.get("http://www.dinamalar.com/user_comments.asp?uid=14701&name=%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%AE%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%B4%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%9A%E0%AF%86%E0%AE%B2%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%A9%E0%AF%8D")

# initial wait for the page to load
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".morered")))

pages = 1
while True:
    browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".morered")[-1].click()

    # wait for more "load more" buttons to be present
    try:
        wait.until(lambda browser: len(browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".morered")) > pages)
    except TimeoutException:
        break  # no more data loaded, exit the loop

    print("Comments loaded: %d" % len(browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".dateg")))

    pages += 1

browser.close()
```

Note that I've also removed that extra space inside the URL.

Comment: Thanks that works fine. I am beginner to this, so how to get comments

Comment: @VinayakumarR I would use an XPath here: `comments = [element.text for element in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='boxcmt1']//a[@class='heading']/following-sibling::div")]`. Please test. Thanks.

Comment: After adding this line to existing code,showing warning I/O warning Non ASCII found, but i try to run it, It shows an error

Comment: This works fine  comments = [element.text for element in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='boxcmt1']//a[@class='heading']")] but it returns unicode

Comment: @VinayakumarR sure, but what's the problem with unicode? Thanks.

Comment: if i use xpath as //*[@id="commsec"]/div[2]/div[1]. i will get only unicode of comments and also i tried with //div[@class='boxcmt1']//a[@class='heading']/fol‌​lowing-sibling::div generates an error. Could you tell exactly how to retrieve comments.

Comment: @VinayakumarR sorry, I'm not exactly sure what the problem is. Anyway, it probably makes sense for you to create a separate question about this problem and resolve this topic. Thanks.

Comment: thanks i am able to extract all comments and but how to extract comments from http://tamil.oneindia.com/news/tamilnadu/the-aiadmk-will-fear-on-12-mlas-says-karunanidhi-254764.html They used vuukle for posting comments